# replace column values in spark dataframe based on dictionary similar to np.where

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data frame looks like -

```
no          city         amount   
1           Kenora        56%
2           Sudbury       23%
3           Kenora        71%
4           Sudbury       41%
5           Kenora        33%
6           Niagara       22%
7           Hamilton      88%
```

It consist of 92M records. I want my data frame looks like -

```
no          city         amount      new_city
1           Kenora        56%           X
2           Niagara       23%           X       
3           Kenora        71%           X
4           Sudbury       41%           Sudbury       
5           Ottawa        33%           Ottawa
6           Niagara       22%           X
7           Hamilton      88%           Hamilton
```

Using python I can manage it(using `np.where`) but not getting any results in pyspark. Any help?

I have done so far -

```
#create dictionary
city_dict = {'Kenora':'X','Niagara':'X'}

mapping_expr  = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*city_dict .items())])

#lookup and replace 
df= df.withColumn('new_city', mapping_expr[df['city']])

#But it gives me wrong results.

df.groupBy('new_city').count().show()

new_city    count
   X          2
  null        3
```

Why gives me null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `mapping_expr` will return `null` for any city that is not contained in `city_dict`. A quick fix is to use [`coalesce`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) to return the `city` if the `mapping_expr` returns a `null` value:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

#lookup and replace 
df1= df.withColumn('new_city', coalesce(mapping_expr[df['city']], df['city']))
df1.show()
#+---+--------+------+--------+
#| no|    city|amount|new_city|
#+---+--------+------+--------+
#|  1|  Kenora|   56%|       X|
#|  2| Sudbury|   23%| Sudbury|
#|  3|  Kenora|   71%|       X|
#|  4| Sudbury|   41%| Sudbury|
#|  5|  Kenora|   33%|       X|
#|  6| Niagara|   22%|       X|
#|  7|Hamilton|   88%|Hamilton|
#+---+--------+------+--------+

df1.groupBy('new_city').count().show()
#+--------+-----+
#|new_city|count|
#+--------+-----+
#|       X|    4|
#|Hamilton|    1|
#| Sudbury|    2|
#+--------+-----+
```

The above method will fail, however, if one of the replacement values is `null`.

In this case, an easier alternative may be to use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace):

First use `withColumn` to create `new_city` as a copy of the values from the `city` column.

```python
df.withColumn("new_city", df["city"])\
    .replace(to_replace=city_dict.keys(), value=city_dict.values(), subset="new_city")\
    .groupBy('new_city').count().show()
#+--------+-----+
#|new_city|count|
#+--------+-----+
#|       X|    4|
#|Hamilton|    1|
#| Sudbury|    2|
#+--------+-----+
```