# Spark UDF with dictionary argument fails

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column (myCol) in a Spark dataframe that has values 1,2 and I want to create a new column with the description of this values like 1-> 'A', 2->'B' etc

I know that this can be done with a join but I tried this because it seems more elegant:

```
dictionary= { 1:'A' , 2:'B' }

add_descriptions = udf(lambda x , dictionary: dictionary[x] if x in dictionary.keys() else None)

df.withColumn("description",add_descriptions(df.myCol,dictionary))
```

And it fails with error

> ```
> lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.function  s.col. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Is it not possible to have a user difined function with dictionaries as arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace column values in spark dataframe based on dictionary similar to np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767536/replace-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-based-on-dictionary-similar-to-np-where)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you just have to do it a bit differently.

```py
dictionary= { 1:'A' , 2:'B' }

def add_descriptions(in_dict):
    def f(x):
        return in_dict.get(x)
    return udf(f)

df.withColumn(
    "description",
    add_descriptions(dictionary)(df.myCol)
)
```

If you want to add directly your dict in the UDF, as UDFs only accept columns as argument, you need to have a map column to replace your dict.

Comment: So the problem is that by definition UDF does not accept dictionaries?

Comment: Also performance wise is this more efficient than a broadcast join with the reference table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spark >= 2.4.0 you can also use the build-in `map_from_arrays` function in order to create map on the fly and then get the desired value with `getItem` as shown below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, map_from_arrays, array
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1],[2],[3]]).toDF("key")

dict = { 1:'A' , 2:'B' }

map_keys = array([lit(k) for k in dict.keys()])
map_values = array([lit(v) for v in dict.values()])
map_func = map_from_arrays(map_keys, map_values) 

df = df.withColumn("description", map_func.getItem(df.key))
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+
|key|description|
+---+-----------+
|  1|          A|
|  2|          B|
|  3|       null|
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre! Do you have to broadcast the above or it is not necessary? I have a similar case where I work with a broadcased dictionary within a UDF, but looks like your approach does not need any broadcast...

Comment: I think that it is not necessary since Spark will pack it and send it together with the task code

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve this with a dictionary that's been broadcasted (which is the most reliable way to solve the problem because it'll also work with large dictionaries):

```py
def add_descriptions(dict_b):
    def f(x):
        return dict_b.value.get(x)
    return F.udf(f)

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,], [2,], [3,]]).toDF("some_num")
dictionary= { 1:'A' , 2:'B' }
dict_b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(dictionary)
df.withColumn(
    "res",
    add_descriptions(dict_b)(F.col("some_num"))
).show()
```

```
+--------+----+
|some_num| res|
+--------+----+
|       1|   A|
|       2|   B|
|       3|null|
+--------+----+
```

Great question, this is an important design pattern for PySpark programmers to master.