# PySpark Compare Empty Map Literal

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to drop rows in a PySpark DataFrame where a certain column contains an empty map. How do I do this? I can't seem to declare a typed empty MapType against which to compare my column. I have seen that in Scala, you can use `typedLit`, but there seems to be no such equivalent in PySpark. I have also tried using `lit(...)` and casting to a `struct<string,int>` but I have found no acceptable argument for `lit()` (tried using `None` which returns null and `{}` which is an error).

I'm sure this is trivial but I haven't seen any docs on this!

Comment: Hi there, it is possible to provide some sample data for your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using pyspark `size` build-in function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size

df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [(1, {1:'A'} ),
  (2, {2:'B'} ), 
  (3, {3:'C'} ),
  (4, {}),
  (5, None)]
).toDF("id", "map")

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- map: map (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- key: long
#  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

df.withColumn("is_empty", size(col("map")) <= 0).show()

# +---+--------+--------+
# | id|     map|is_empty|
# +---+--------+--------+
# |  1|[1 -> A]|   false|
# |  2|[2 -> B]|   false|
# |  3|[3 -> C]|   false|
# |  4|      []|    true|
# |  5|    null|    true|
# +---+--------+--------+
```

Note that the condition is `size <= 0` since in the case of null the function returns -1 (if the `spark.sql.legacy.sizeOfNull` setting is true otherwise it will return null). [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size) you can find more details.

**Generic solution: comparing Map column and literal Map**

For a more generic solution we can use the build-in function `size` in combination with a UDF which append the string `key + value` of each item into a sorted list (thank you @jxc for pointing out the problem with the previous version). The hypothesis here will be that two maps are equal when:

1. they have the same size
2. the string representation of key + value is identical between the items of the maps

The literal map is created from an arbitrary python dictionary combining keys and values via `map_from_arrays`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit, size, when, map_from_arrays, array

df = spark.createDataFrame([
   [1, {}],
   [2, {1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}],
   [3, {1:'A', 2:'B'}]
  ]).toDF("key", "map")

dict = { 1:'A' , 2:'B' }

map_keys_ = array([lit(k) for k in dict.keys()])
map_values_ = array([lit(v) for v in dict.values()])
tmp_map = map_from_arrays(map_keys_, map_values_) 

to_strlist_udf = udf(lambda d: sorted([str(k) + str(d[k]) for k in d.keys()]))

def map_equals(m1, m2):
  return when(
            (size(m1) == size(m2)) & 
            (to_strlist_udf(m1) == to_strlist_udf(m2)), True
          ).otherwise(False)

df = df.withColumn("equals", map_equals(df["map"], tmp_map))

df.show(10, False)

# +---+------------------------+------+
# |key|map                     |equals|
# +---+------------------------+------+
# |1  |[]                      |false |
# |2  |[1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C]|false |
# |3  |[1 -> A, 2 -> B]        |true  |
# +---+------------------------+------+
```

Note: As you can see the pyspark `==` operator works pretty well for array comparison as well.

Comment: Yes I was doing something similar by doing `map_keys` and checking the length but seems like an unnatural work-around to me

Comment: well size will work for both arrays and dictionaries so you can directly use it

Comment: but what if I wanted to compare to a map of `{'somekey' => 55}` for example, then this doesn't extend to that.

Comment: comparison between a harcoded dictionary and the col value it would be a different problem indeed. Here I just provided a solution of how to check if the map is empty

Comment: yes agreed, maybe I need to ask a separate question about that! Thank you!

Comment: maybe yes but take a look on how to create a map column from an existing python dictionary first. Maybe it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037487/spark-udf-with-dictionary-argument-fails/57038750#57038750

Comment: Hi again, so you want to be able to compare the value of map-column with a hard-coded map correct?

Comment: I guess I looked at the problem like this: I would like to find if a column is equal to an empty Map, hence I just need to find some way of creating an empty Map of a given type and then comparing it to my column. Then I just couldn't figure out how to create an empty map, which seemed silly to me. Your solution did indeed solve my problem but I am curious on how to literally create a map of a given type. Your link shows how to create a map, but I couldn't see any type declarations there. What if I want Int -> Datetime ? But I think that discussion is for a different thread!

Comment: Clear, I will try to update my answer accordingly since it seems interesting

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis map_keys and map_values return unordered arrays, comparison based on arrays of these keys/values could be problematic.

Comment: @jxc I changed the logic and now the comparison is based on a sorted list made of `string(key) + string(value)` items. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrosBiratsis. Wow, what a way to go around the roundabout twice to go straight. Seems like this kind of thing isn't naturally expressed in Spark "SQL" then...

Comment: well as far as I know there is not a build-in function for comparing maps in Spark

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, with spark2.40+, you can use SparkSQL built-in higher-order functions like filter(), exists() to compare two maps based on their map_keys().

Comment: @jxc the above implementation considers two maps identical if the combination of key-value is the same on both maps not only keys and/or values. I couldn't think an alternative for this scenario.

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, I knew your answer is fine. just with spark 2.40+, we can do the same using some Spark SQL built-in functions. For example, assume we have two maps: *m1* from the dataframe and *m2* created from the Python dict. we can create a flag `f` with the following function: `df.withColumn('f', F.expr("exists(map_keys(m2), k -> (m2[k] != m1[k]) or (m1[k] is null))"))`.  this iterates all keys in `m2` and return True if any of m2[k] != m1[k] or m1[k] is NULL.  . On the other hand, if this flag is false, we will have either m1 is the same as m2 or *m2* is the subset of *m1*

Comment: we can then use a filter like `df1.filter('!f and (size(m1) == size(m2))')` to remove the case when m2 is a subset of m1. (do make sure the DataType for keys/values match between m1 and m2).

Comment: Interesting solution @jxc thank you for  providing it. Probably the performance will be better because of the absence of udf