# Replace NULL Values in Spark DataFrame with Dict's Key Value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this `dataframe` and a key: value broadcast variable dictionary.  I want to replace `null` values in the `dataframe`'s *"value"* column with the `dict`'s key value, based on a different column in the dataframe named *"item"* which is the same as the `dict`'s key.

How can this be done?

```py
# mapping
dict = {'temp': '70.0', 'speed': '98', 'wind': 'TRUE'}

# sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device1', 'event', 'temp', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device2', 'sensor', 'speed', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device3', 'monitor', 'wind', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device1', 'event', 'temp', '75.2'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device2', 'sensor', 'speed', '100'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device3', 'monitor', 'wind', 'FALSE'),],\
                            ['date', 'name', 'type', 'item', 'value'])

# current input
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|              date|   name|   type| item|value|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| null|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed| null|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| null|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+

# desired output
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|              date|   name|   type| item|value|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| 70.0|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed|   98|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| TRUE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace column values in spark dataframe based on dictionary similar to np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767536/replace-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-based-on-dictionary-similar-to-np-where)

Comment: FWIW, that's not my downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) and [create_map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, lit, create_map, col
from itertools import chain 

map_dict = create_map(*[ lit(e) for e in chain.from_iterable(dict.items()) ])
# Column<b'map(temp, 70.0, speed, 98, wind, TRUE)'>

df.withColumn('value', coalesce('value', map_dict[col('item')])).show()
#+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
#|              date|   name|   type| item|value|
#+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| 70.0|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed|   98|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| TRUE|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
#+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

For a very large dict mapping, you might create a dataframe and do a left join:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, broadcast

df_map = spark.createDataFrame(dict.items(), ['item', 'map_value'])

df.join(broadcast(df_map), on=['item'], how='left') \
  .withColumn('value', coalesce('value', 'map_value')) \
  .drop('map_value') \
  .show()
```

Comment: thank you!  will close this soon if there is no a way to avoid ```itertools```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `itertools`?

Comment: my list could range between 100-500 mapped values so was concerned it might cause performance problems and work outside spark's ```catalyst``` optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

Using withColumn:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

dict = {'temp': '70.0', 'speed': '98', 'wind': 'TRUE'}
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device1', 'event', 'temp', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device2', 'sensor', 'speed', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'device3', 'monitor', 'wind', None),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device1', 'event', 'temp', '75.2'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device2', 'sensor', 'speed', '100'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'device3', 'monitor', 'wind', 'FALSE'),],\
                            ['date', 'name', 'type', 'item', 'value'])
def replace_null(a,b):
  if b is None:
    return dict[a]
  else:
    return b

replace_null_udf = udf(replace_null, StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("tmp", replace_null_udf(col("item"),col("value")))
df2.show()
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|              date|   name|   type| item|  tmp|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| 70.0|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed|   98|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| TRUE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
df3 = df2.drop("value").withColumnRenamed('tmp','value')
df3.show()
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|              date|   name|   type| item|value|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| 70.0|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed|   98|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| TRUE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: thanks!  definitely want to avoid ```udf```s for python performance reasons though.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider below solution

```
mapping = {'temp': '70.0', 'speed': '98', 'wind': 'TRUE'}

mappingDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(list(mapping.items()) , ['item_t', 'value_t'])

df = df.join(mappingDf, df.item==mappingDf.item_t)
df = df.withColumn('value', F.when(F.col('value').isNotNull(), df.value).otherwise(df.value_t)).drop('item_t').drop('value_t')
df.show()
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|              date|   name|   type| item|value|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device1|  event| temp| 70.0|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device1|  event| temp| 75.2|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device3|monitor| wind| TRUE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device3|monitor| wind|FALSE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|device2| sensor|speed|   98|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|device2| sensor|speed|  100|
+------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: thanks!  this is good.